# equivalent for VB6.TwipsPerPixelX in vb.net without using Microsoft.Visualbasic.Compatibility.dll

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

During migration from VB6 to VB.NET the **Screen.TwipsPerPixelX** function is converted to **VB6.TwipsPerPixelX**, which is defined in **Microsoft.Visualbasic.Compatibility.dll**.

I dont want to use **Microsoft.Visualbasic.Compatibility.dll**. Is there any equivalent for this in .NET.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use TwipsPerPixel in .NET - unless you are doing a line for line conversion. If you are doing the latter prepare for a world of hurt...

Answer (score 1):

Vb.net no longer use [Twips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip), so there's no need for such a function